# The BasicStroke.class file of the JRE System Library does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, awt

Help!
I use Eclipse IDE. After copying an `.png` image into the `rsc` folder of my project, I have run into a really strange problem. All of a sudden, when I tried to run my application there occured:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    BasicStroke cannot be resolved to a type
```

If I go to JRE System Library->java.desktop->java.awt and click on BasicStroke.class, there appears:

```
BasicStroke.class [in java.awt [in <module:java.desktop>]] does not exist
```

How can I fix it???

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of Eclipse? What version of Java? Show us a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Obviously it was just a small bug. Fixed it by restarting eclipse :D

Comment: I encountered the same problem with javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder. Here, too, the problem was resolved when I restarted eclipse.